# Proving that a bipartite graph, of minimum degree $4$, doesn't contain $K_{3,3}$

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

> Prove that a bipartite graph, of minimum degree $4$, doesn't necessarily contain $K_{3,3}$

I know I just need a counter example, but I'm having some extreme difficulty finding one.

Comment: Do you mean "doesn't necessarily contain"?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Because there are loads of bipartite graphs of minimum degree $4$ which _do_ contain $K_{3, 3}$ (such as any $K_{m, n}$ with $m, n \geq 4$). What you want is one example that it isn't _always_ so, right?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a bipartite graph with minimum degree $4$ which *doesn't* contain $K_{3,3}$, then here's one:

[image: Bipartite example]

The different coloured edges are just for clarity, it's a messy drawing.

Comment: AWW ya, you the best, thanks homie.